# running gem5 with SPEC2006

Tags: gem5

when running GEM5 X86 in SE mode, I am trying to run bzip2 from SPEC2006, at first it was failing because it says it can't run dynamic execution so I compiled it with -static flag.
now I get this error:

```
gem5 Simulator System.  http://gem5.org
gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 compiled Oct 27 2018 00:36:02
gem5 started Dec 22 2018 18:16:40
gem5 executing on Dan
command line: ./build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/se.py -c /home/dan/SPEC2006/benchspec/CPU2006/401.bzip2/exe/bzip2_base.ia64-gcc42 -i /home/dan/SPEC2006/benchspec/CPU2006/401.bzip2/data/test/input/dryer.jpg

Could not import 03_BASE_FLAT
Could not import 03_BASE_NARROW
Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second
warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (4096 Mbytes)
0: system.remote_gdb.listener: listening for remote gdb #0 on port 7000
**** REAL SIMULATION ****
info: Entering event queue @ 0.  Starting simulation...
panic: Tried to write unmapped address 0xffffedd8. Inst is at 0x400da4
 @ tick 5500
[invoke:build/X86/arch/x86/faults.cc, line 160]
Memory Usage: 4316736 KBytes
Program aborted at tick 5500
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am running gem5 on ubuntu 17.10.
I tried to find solutions in google but I didn't see any one referring to this problem, does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Have you managed to run a hello world program on SE? GDB step debug both gem5 and the guest program and objdump your binary to narrow down what those addresses mean, and why they are different than your working hello world.

Comment: hello program is working properly:
**** REAL SIMULATION ****
info: Entering event queue @ 0.  Starting simulation...
Hello world!
Exiting @ tick 2992250 because target called exit()

I tried several SPEC programs without any success

Comment: 400da4: 67 e8 46 b3 00 00     addr32 callq 40c0f0 <__libc_start_main>
this is the instruction at 400da4

Answer (score 0):

Please check your host machine configuration. Bzip2 does not work in a 32-bit machine. My desktop is dual core have 32-bit X86 architecture, I tried to run bzip2 it had shown same error.